# Mahadeva/Shiva's origin

Tags: shiva

I read Brahma originated from of Narayana's naval lotus.
How did Shiva originate?
He was there to marry Daksha's daughter; he was made lord of Rudras. Interested to learn about his birth/origin.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Shiva was born from Lord Brahma's anger.

> Although he tried to curb his anger, it came out from between his
> eyebrows, and a child mixed blue and red was immediately generated.
> -ŚB 3.12.7

When this child was born, he started crying for name and position.

> Thereafter Brahmā said: O chief of the demigods, you shall be called by the name Rudra by all people because you have so anxiously cried.
> -ŚB 3.12.10

It was Bramha who named him Rudra (because he cried during his birth) and his residences were the the heart, the senses, the air of life, the sky, the air, the fire, the water, the earth, the sun, the moon and austerity.

Brahma gave many names to Rudra such as Shiva, Kapali ect.